# Accessibility - focus management and ARIA tags for a SPA (Single Page Application)

Tags: angular, accessibility, single-page-application

I am retrofitting accessibility standards (https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/quickref/?versions=2.1) to an existing SPA (Angular) application - the screen layout is as follows :-

[image]

Basically when the user initially arrives they see (as the image suggests) empty "Report filter fields" in the top half and the "landing text" in the bottom half. The user fills in "Report filtering fields" (which includes selecting one of many reports) and clicks the "Generate report button" and the generated report appears in the bottom half (**note that each report can be quite verbose**)

I am using a range of browsers and I am using a range of screen readers (Windows screen reader, NVDA, ChomeVox)

I have a few questions regarding what should happen when the user clicks the "Generate report button"

- I have experimented with setting focus to the bottom half of the screen so the screen reader can go ahead and read the report - the problem with this is that even though I have a added a number of role/aria tags (eg. role="headings", aria-level=..., table role tags) within the report these are ignored.  Is this approach worth pursuing (assuming I can get the roles/aria-tags honoured by the screen reader when focus is set) ?
- Should I leave the focus on the Generate report button and use a "Skip to content" link strategy so the user can manually skip to the report ?
- Should I use an aria-live (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) "polite"/"assertive" strategy - set the report markup to have changed when the "Generate report button" is clicked (note that like the first point, focusing, this too doesn't honour the roles/aria-tags in the report) ?
- Should I set the browser Window title to say the report name when the "Generate report button" is clicked ?

When I look at the WCAG/ADA standards they don't provide recommendations specific to SPA apps

Any assistance would be gratefully received